# automatically create a directory structure for a project in document management

Tags: python, odoo, document

I am trying to configure OpenERP such that every project created, a directory structure is automatically created.

For example,once project is created 1. a top level directory for the project is created. 2. inside this project directory I want to create directories like 'drawings', 'reports', 'photos'. 3. The project directory should be accessible only to project users. 4. Also additional permissions have to set on directories like 'photos' should viewable by customer by not editable